# How to Get Response From NADA API?

Tags: ios

https://demo.nadaguideswebservices.com/UsedCarsService.svc?wsdl?Username=xxxxxxx&Password=xxxxxxx

I am use this link to get response from **NADA** API. I don't know how to work in **NADA** in iOS.

How to pass parameter to get info form **NADA**.